# VBA _set subranges to calculate moving average

Tags: excel, vba, average

Please kindly let me know how to properly set the partial range of a table that serves as source of values for calculating their simple moving average, subrange by subrange.
( source sheet of data is named as "Skandi", the destination sheet for recording average values is named as "MovAvg" )

The fault stems in the below declaration of the VBA script, marked by red colour in the module:

```
Sub movingaverage()

Dim MovAvg As Worksheet: Set MovAvg = Sheets("MovAvg")
Dim Skandi As Worksheet: Set Skandi = Sheets("Skandi")
Dim xHeti As Long: xHeti = 6      ' time span for calculating averages
Dim sz As Long: sz = 35       ' Nr of columns in table
Dim Col As Long                   
Dim Row As Long                  

For Col = 1 To sz
    For Row = 1 To Skandi.Range("namedRange").Rows.Count
     Dim fCell As Range: Set fCell = Skandi.Range("namedRange").Cells(Row, Col)    
     Dim lCell As Range: Set lCell = Skandi.Range("namedRange").Cells(Row + xHeti, Col)
     Dim AvgRng As Range: Set AvgRng = Range(fCell, lCell)                                                                         
        MovAvg.Cells(7 + Row, Col) = WorksheetFunction.Average(AvgRng)     ' fault here. Marked yellow !                                                  
       
    Next Row
Next Col
End Sub
```

I reviewed the relevant Q&A -s on this website, but those ones have not yet provided bailout for me.

Answer (score 2):

(at least) 2 problems with your code:

a) Before you can use `iFirst` and `iLast` as parameter for the range `iRange`, you need to set them. In your code, they are declared but are set to `Nothing`, and you can't create a `Range` from `Nothing`.

b) The correct syntax in VBA to create a Range from 2 Ranges is to separate the 2 Range parameter with comma, not a `:` (that would be Excel syntax).

```
Dim iRange As Range

For Col = 1 To sz
    For Row = 1 To Skandi.Range("namedrange").Rows.Count
         Set iFirst = Skandi.Range("namedrange").Cells(Row, Col)
         Set iLast = Skandi.Range("namedrange").Cells(Row + xHeti, Col)
         Set iRange = Range(ifirst, ilast)
         MovAvg.Cells(7 + Row, Col) = WorksheetFunction.Average(iRange)
     Next Row
Next Col
```

P.S. you have a strange naming convention: Why do you put a prefix `i` in front of the range variable names?

Comment: Thanks. I have applied corrections accordingly in the original script. ( see above) Though the orignal failure has been solved, a new problem has arisen in row "MovAvg.Cells(7 + Row, Col) = WorksheetFunction.Average(AvgRng)" What is wrong here ?

Comment: On SO, the idea is to ask a question and get an answer (or several) to that. This new problem would be a new question. But before you ask a new question: Check the range `iRange`: Does it contain any (numeric) data? Is this the range you expect? Usually, the `Average` fails if the range contains data that is not valid for average calculation.

Comment: Just doublechecked it. The answer is: yes, it does contain numeric values, and only numeric ones. Still the program hangs up at the cited script line. Don't know why.